# How to remove the active class from first li-item while other one is active using JavaScript(!important))

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on an old site where only JavaScript codes are working. Problem is: the active class is working but while clicking on other "li",  the li "Home" still remains active. Please suggest what other code need to be added in JS. Thanks in advance!
The code are:

```js
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('navmenu').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (i = 0; i < aObj.length; i++) {
    if (document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href) >= 0) {
      aObj[i].className = 'active';
    }
  }
}

window.onload = setActive;
```

```html
<div id="navmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/Home/Vision">Vision</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/Home/Career">Career</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Do you know why that happens?

Comment: do you want to see how to do this without using JavaScript?

Comment: also, where is the `!important`? you want rid of that if you can, that would make things nicer :-) - though, if it's there as a result of code you don't currently control then this is harder

Answer (score 1):

When you use `indexOf()`, you're testing whether `aObj[i].href` is anywhere in `document.location.href`, you're not testing whether it exactly matches the path. Since `/` is in `/Home/Vision`, that test succeeds. Try doing an exact match of `document.location.pathname`.

```js
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('navmenu').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (i = 0; i < aObj.length; i++) {
    if (document.location.pathname == aObj[i].href) {
      aObj[i].className = 'active';
    }
  }
}

window.onload = setActive;
```

```html
<div id="navmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/Home/Vision">Vision</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/Home/Career">Career</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Barmar. But after changing my code with your one, it is not at all working! Really,don't understand what to do!!

Comment: I made a small mistake, it's `.pathname`.

Comment: When I use debugger, it says: setActive();
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null ... Why so?

Comment: It's not finding the `id="navmenu"`. Make sure you spelled everything correctly.

Comment: Are you adding the nav menu dynamically? The error message means that `document.getElementById('navmenu')` is returning `null`, which would only happen if there's no `navmenu` element yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below link works with you.

http://jsfiddle.net/FnK9D/16/

```
function setActive(){aObj = document.getElementById('navmenu').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (i = 0; i < aObj.length; i++) {
        if (document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href) >= 0) {
            aObj[i].className = 'active';
         }
    }
}

window.onload = setActive;
```

Comment: Thanks Steevan. But my problem still remains the same! Do we have any code like removeclass(active) in JS? Please suggest!